# Python : ImportError: cannot import name callfunc

Tags: python

I'm Python newbie, and I have a problem with an error message

'ImportError: cannot import name callfunc'

I made two python files, '`~/a.py`' and '`~/pkg/b.py`'. (Additionally my IDE automatically created '`~/__init__.py`' and '`~/pkg/__init__.py`')

in a.py, a function

```
def callfunc():
    print "Called"
```

is defined, and there are two statements in pkg/b.py:

```
from a import callfunc
callfunc()
```

However when executing python pkg/b.py, an error raises :

```
ImportError: cannot import name callfunc
```

I tried export PYTHONPATH=... , but it isn't effective also

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: does your PYTHONPATH contain 3 `.` or is it a typo...

Answer (score 2):

write this in b.py before any of the imports from your own modules:-

```
import sys
sys.path.append(<the directory where a.py is defined>)
```

Comment: Wow.. This worked. I found my PYTHONPATH was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

what the value of PYTHONPATH?

The parameter can be $HOME in your example.